# What does "run of house" mean with regard to hotel room type

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have seen a room type at a hotel like below;

> Family Room 2 Bedrooms & Living Room Run of The House

Everything is OK except the `Run of The House` thing. What does it exactly mean here? AFAIK, it is whatever room is available when you check-in. Is that true? Or does that have some other meanings?

Comment: yup you're right, whatever is available.

Comment: So, it is like lottery?

Comment: i would rather call it the "whims and fancies" of the management at that time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run of House, or ROH, generally means you will be staying in a room decided upon by the hotel. In it's simplest form, ROH means you will get whatever room is available at the time you check-in.

If the hotel has a deluxe room or a suite available, you "could" get a nicer room than you would have if you had requested a specific type of accommodation, but you could be booked into a lesser valued room. It all depends on the hotel and how the hotel handles Run of House.

Sometimes, a hotel will have a specific type of room which is their standard Run of House room, which will be booked to those that do not request a specific room type.

If you want a specific room, view, or location, go ahead and choose it unless you are choosing the most basic room the hotel offers, then you might be better off to choose ROH, and hope for something a step or more better than the basic room.

Comment: What does "run" mean anyway?

Answer (score 3):

It is not like the lottery.

ROH means that you will get the room you requested, or better.

Say the hotel has Junior Suites, Standart Suites and Master Suites and you book a Standart Suite (the middle size)

You will probably get a Standart Suite, but you might get a Master Suite with no extra charge. But you will NEVER get a Junior Suite because it will be less that what you have booked (and paid)

Comment: ... Serious? So basically always go for it?